# Convert TFS 2013 xaml Build Definition to TFS 2015 vNext Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have build definitions that are XAML based and would like to convert these to vNext builds (we have recently upgraded to TFS 2015).  Can this be done?

What is the most efficient way to convert a xaml build definition to a vNext build definition?

Comment: It's totally different technology.  I don't think there will be any automated ways of converting. So your "conversion" process will probably have to involve documenting what your existing build does and re-inventing it.  I'm not familiar with `XAML` build defs much, but I like the vNext stuff.  (Except for some reason I cant seem to get successful builds to feature in other Work Items - e.g. `Bug`, etc)... Well not without manual powershell which is a bit annoying

Comment: You should take a look at [these series of articles](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2016/01/upgrading-from-xaml-to-build-2015-with.html) by @jessehouwing devoted specifically to the case like yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will not be any automated conversion processes, unfortunately.  But here are some [pointers from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/feature-overview), which may help you:

> The new builds are based on a different architecture and run on a completely different system.

and

> You can use both the new builds and agents alongside your XAML builds,
>   controllers, and agents.

and finally:

> If you have heavily customized XAML builds and custom activities, you
>   can continue using those builds until you are ready to port your
>   business logic into scripts that can run in the new builds.